# Close menu by clicking on any screen place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have a script thats open menu and closes after clicking on 'li' element, how to close it by clicking on any place on screen ?

```
$(function() {
  $('.drop-down-input').click(function() {
  $('.drop-down-input.selected').removeClass('selected'); // Forget the previous selection
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $(this).find(".dropdown-list").show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".drop-down-input.selected li",
  function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.drop-down-input.selected .dropdown-list').hide().siblings().val($(this).html());
  });
});
```

Thats my HTML:

```
<div class="styled-input-container drop-down-input">
                       <input id="simple_2" class="drop-down-select" placeholder="input text" type="text">
                       <ul class="dropdown-list">
                           <li>eeee</li>
                           <li>xxxx</li>
                           <li>xxxx</li>
                           <li>xsssxxx</li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
```

Comment: @Erop Kpotehko please share jsfflde or codepen thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5psu7ovu/2/ - styles not working, but it's not matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps :)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    // change from grey to blue color input
    
    
  $(".styled-input-container input").focus(function () {
     $id = this.id;
     $idgen = '#' + $id;
     //console.log($idgen);
     
     $($idgen).closest( "div" ).addClass('focused');
    });
    
    $(".styled-input-container input").blur(function() {
        $('.styled-input-container').removeClass('focused');
        
    });
  
  
    
    //open % close ul list input
    
   $(function() {
  $('.drop-down-input').click(function() {
  $('.drop-down-input.selected').removeClass('selected'); // Forget the previous selection
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $(this).find(".dropdown-list").show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".drop-down-input.selected li",
  function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.drop-down-input.selected .dropdown-list').hide().siblings().val($(this).html());
  });
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var container = $(".dropdown-list");

    if (!container.is(e.target)
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="styled-input-container">
                       <input id="simple_1" placeholder="input text" type="text">
                   
                   </div>
                   <div class="separator"></div>
                   <div class="styled-input-container drop-down-input">
                       <input id="simple_2" class="drop-down-select" placeholder="input text" type="text">
                       <ul class="dropdown-list">
                           <li>eeee</li>
                           <li>xxxx</li>
                           <li>xxxx</li>
                           <li>xsssxxx</li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a listener on all the dom like this:

```
$(document).on('click', ':not(.drop-down-input.selected li)',function() {/* Close all open menus  */});
```

See than you can just ignore the li element with the :not selector to prevent listen the click on that elements.

Comment: please, Can you show with my code, don't understand how to implement that

Comment: <code>$(document).on('click', ':not(.drop-down-input.selected li)',function() {
      
      $(".dropdown-list.selected").hide();
      
  });<code> not working